# AngularJS ui-view coming back blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

I am trying to set up a simple login screen.  Why is this coming back blank?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Joe Kleckler</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="kleckDev">
        <div ui-view></div> 
    </body>
    <script src="./app/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/ui.router.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/kleckDev.js"></script>

    <script src="./app/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/controllers/realmController.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="./app/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("angular object", angular);
    </script>
</html>
```

kleckDev.js

```
var app = angular.module('kleckDev', ["ui.router"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {   
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url: "/",
            controller: "LoginController",
            templateUrl: "views/login.html"
        })
        .state("realm", {
            url:"/realm",
            controller: "RealmController",
            templateUrl: "views/realm.html"
        })
});
```

loginController.js

```
app.controller("LoginController", ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {

    $scope.registration = {
        firstName: undefined,
        lastName: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        password: undefined,
        checkPass: undefined
    }

    $scope.login = {
        username: undefined,
        password: undefined
    }

    $scope.registerUser = function() {
        var data = {
            firstName: $scope.registration.firstName,
            lastName: $scope.registration.lastName,
            email: $scope.registration.email,
            username : $scope.registration.username,
            password : $scope.registration.password,
            checkPass : $scope.registration.checkPass,
            access: 0

        }

        $http.post("php/register.php", data).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({user: response}));
            $state.go("realm");
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

    $scope.loginUser = function() {
        var data = {
            username: $scope.login.username,
            password: $scope.login.password
        }

        $http.post("php/login.php", data).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({user: response[0].username}));
            $state.go("realm");
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}])
```

It was showing up less than an hour ago, and I tried to add something, but when I removed it cuz it broke stuff nothing will show now.

[image]

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: there isn't any errors in the console

Comment: The file structure is correct? The Views are in place and the controllers are named correctly?

Comment: I added an image of the file structure.  It should be correct,  It was working fine until I tried to add the realm state, at first, it went there, but couldn't find the javascript file.  Then I added the file, like I should of had in the first place, and then nothing started happening.  Blank Screen,  I proceeded to remove the realm state and everything, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` file is already inside the app directory. Nothing works because it doesn't load angular or any of the specified files.

remove the `./app` directory from all your script sources.

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src=".ui.router.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/realmController.js"></script>
<script src="kleckDev.js"></script>
```

And load the `kleckDev.js` file last.

Comment: what is the correct way to set up a controller? I need the kleckDev.js to happen first because the controllers use the module from kleckDev

Comment: I added the loginController.js to the post as well.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Did you try to reorder the scripts in index.html?

Comment: I edited my answer. The problem is that you specify the app directory while the index.html is already in the app directory

Comment: That's not correct, index.html is in KlecklDev, the app directory is only js files

Comment: Did you try to reorder the files?

Comment: When I reorder the files it can't find the kleckDev module that the controllers are a part of

Comment: Did you put it in the order that I suggested?

Comment: The order that you suggested gives an error, I still have had no luck getting this to work again